# PySpark (1.6.2) DataFrame column append

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have two PySpark (1.6.2) data frame

```
df1 = spark.range(3).toDF("c1")
df2 = spark.range(5,8).toDF("c2")
```

How to create 3rd data frame which is simple column append (Similar to 'cbind' in R)

I am aware of join and UnionAll. Not working.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why you would want to join without at least some reference? If you wanted to add multiple columns you should use `withColumn` - I think you are trying to do something that is not correct. If you really wanted to do this

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.sql import Window
df1 = df1.select("c1",F.row_number().over(Window.orderBy("c1")).alias("dummy_id")) 
df2 = df2.select("c2",F.row_number().over(Window.orderBy("c2")).alias("dummy_id"))

df1.join(df2, "dummy_id").drop("dummy_id").show()
```

Does what you want - But I still believe what you want is not optimal.

Comment: in SPark1.6.2, Getting error "Could not resolve window function 'row_number'. Note that, using window functions currently requires a HiveContext;"